Not sure if this is a valid way of proving local maximum
I am unsure if my argument makes sense:
Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x) = \frac{1}{q}$ if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ in lowest terms.
The exercise asks to find all local maximum and minimum:
I see that the irrationals are all local minimum and that in particular the natural numbers are all local maximum. Now, I convinced myself that any other rational is indeed also a local maximum. However the proof is what I am not so sure about...
I said that given a rational number $x = \frac{p}{q} $, if you look at numbers that are not further than $\delta := Min(|p'/q'-x|,gcd(p',q') = 1, q' < q) $ then by definition of $\delta$ there will be no number with greater value of $f$.

The idea is correct, but the argument maybe needs a bit of polishing.
Take $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$. If a point $y=\dfrac{a}{b}$ verifies that $f(y)=\dfrac{1}{b}>\dfrac{1}{q}=f(x)$ then we must have $b<q$.
There is only a finite number of such $b$'s, and for a fixed $b$ there is only a finite number of $a$'s such that $|x-y|=\left|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|<1$ (this $1$ is just a choice, any other positive number would do).
Denoting $\delta=\min\left\{\left|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|: b<q, \left|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|<1 \right\},$ we get that, if $|x-y|<\delta, $ then $f(x)\ge f(y)$, proving that $x$ is a local maximum.
Without the restriction that $\left|\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|<1$, it is not so clear that the minimum of all those quantities exists, as there is an infinite number of $\dfrac{a}{b}$ such that $b<q$.

Okay, thanks. So the final touch you added is showing that the argument inside the Min has finite size so that it exists.

Yes, exactly that.

@Alejandro In other problems one may need to consider infinitely many cases. In that case, the minumum must be replaced by the infimum (a minumum may not exist). The hard part then is usually proving that the infimum is bigger than zero. For finitely many positive numbers the minimum is positive, but for infinitely many ones the infimum may not be.
